# Saleforce1 tour London Anyone?

Tags: discussion

Somewhat off-topic, but we've had these topics before. May 22nd the [Salesforce 1 tour event](https://www.salesforce.com/uk/events/details/sf1wt14-london/) is taking place in London. It would be nice to meet some people who're active here.

Or maybe, are some presenting some of the breakout sessions ? The site doesn't list the presenters.

Comment: I can't attend the event itself (project commitments) but I'd love to meet in the pub afterwards :) Are you thinking about ExCel area or something in the City?

Comment: @eyescream   How about the evening before?

Comment: Sure, why not :) It'll take me a while to reach the City but if I'll know ahead how are we going to meet I'm sure my manager will let me shave 1-2h off to arrive on time.

Comment: Has there been any movement on this? I'm sure I can duck out of one of the events after the World Tour if an SE event is happening.

Comment: Hi @AlexTennant, how about Wed evening? I've poked... hm, replied to a poke from Samuel at LinkedIn, looks promising. I should be available on Thu too, ideally after 7 wherever you want (wait, this sounds wrong...)

Comment: @eyescream I didn't notice this until now, I'm not going to be in London tonight, I'm not coming over until tomorrow morning. I'm struggling to find time during Thursday now as apparently I've committed to an awful lot more than I thought tomorrow. An SE meetup might to be an idea for another time.

Comment: @AlexTennant no probs at all :) And you're more than welcome to attack one of http://www.meetup.com/LondonSalesforceDevelopers/ for example (usually I'm bit lazy to attend but we could take over / piggyback on one of these)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There will be some blog posts published in the coming week introducing more features of the DevZone.

Mentionables would be Keir (aka Bob Buzzard), Andy Fawcett, Carolina Ruiz, Wes Nolte, James Melville, Ritesh (aka TechTrekker), Simon Goodyear, Simon Lawrence, Chris Lewis and many more (as that's just who I can think of off the top of my head).

Many of these will be beholden to their company sponsored parties afterwards, but perhaps we could find a group of stragglers and look for a good pub to meet up at. The SSE stragglers after party?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned here by Peter I am presenting on the developer stage with my colleague (and fellow Force.com MVP) Chris Lewis. We're delivering a session on Testing on the SFDC Platform at 15:00.

I don't know if any of the specific geo-based communities (like our one in Bristol, or the London User Group) are planning any flash-mob style get togethers, but schedule allowing, I could be interested in meeting some fellow StackExchangers!

I'll keep an eye out on here for any developments in the idea :)

Comment: Nice! Was there a "call for papers" or such, through which you presented?

Comment: There wasn't a call for papers on the World Tour, as there is just the one main Developer Theatre stage (as far as I am aware) the presenting schedule was put together by the London Deverloper Evangelists and Developer Relations team, consisting mostly of themselves and the UK Community Organisers/MVPs.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be there along with my colleagues Chris Lewis and Simon Lawrence who will be presenting. I doubt I'll have any invites to fancy sponsored parties so a StackExchange stragglers party sounds like an excellent idea to me.

Answer (score 2):

There is a blog post coming very soon that will cover the developer related activities happening during the London World Tour.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/

In brief, there is an area called DevZone that will have:

- 12 technical presentations on different aspects of the Salesforce1 Plaform (9am - 5.30pm)
- A developer library with a range of free books and workbooks
- Quickstart sessions to get you going with Salesforce1 enterprise mobile app development & Heroku
- Minihack competition - 2 challenges to complete to enter the raffle for an iPad Air
- 1 on 1 expert consultations (you need to pre-register) http://developer.force.com/events/eventConsult?event=S1L14

There will also be a breakout session on "Building Mobile Web Apps on Salesforce1 platform" at 4.30pm.

Hope that helps.

John

Comment: Will any of the dev zone sessions be streamed live?

Comment: Hello Gaurav.  I am afraid the DevZone sessions at the London World tour will not be recorded or streamed.  Some of the sessions will be repeated at the Paris (26th June) & Munich (3rd July) World Tour events.

Comment: Gaurav, it seems you are based in India.  If you are part of a Salesforce Developer group in your area then we could arrange for someone to give one of the talks to at a meetup event, over GoTo meeting.  For details of Salesforce developer groups take a look at: https://developer.salesforce.com/dugs?title=page/Force.com_User_Groups

Comment: jr0cket - Thanks for the reply. I'm an active speaker in a couple of Force.com User Groups in India. I also presented during the recently concluded Salesforce1 Dev Week along with Raja Rao so we don't really need a GoToMeeting session or anything like that. I was just curious if the sessions would be streamed or not so I asked, thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2):

I'm up for meeting up... subject to the lure of free food and drink :)